# Thread does not execute 2 different functions 4 times after waiting for signal

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

**Introduction**

With this program I intend to learn <semaphore.h> and <pthread.h> in C code and this is something I came up with to test my current basic knowledge.

This program simulates a production line for product Q and R:

Q needs 1A, 1B, 1C and R needs 1A, 1C.

Both functions produce_Q and produce_R share those same resources

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sem_worker[2]; //Semaphores (workers)

//Current stock (initialized as MAX stock)
int stock_A = 5;
int stock_B = 3;
int stock_C = 5;

//Q production method needs 1A, 1B and 1C
void *produce_Q(void *worker)
{
    int w = (int) worker; //Worker id
    
    //Wait if ther are not enough tools 
    while (stock_A < 1 || stock_B < 1 || stock_C < 1) {
        printf("Not enough resources for worker[%d] for Q\n", w);
        sem_wait(&sem_worker[w]); //Worker set to wait
        sleep(4); //StackOverflow question here
        printf("Resuming worker's [%d] production for Q\n", w);
    }

    //If there are tool to produce then
    printf("Worker[%d] takes resources from pool for Q\n", w);
    stock_A--;
    stock_B--;
    stock_C--;
    printf("Stock: A=%d, B=%d, C=%d left\n", stock_A, stock_B, stock_C);

    //Random wait to simulate prod
    sleep(rand() % 4);
    printf("Worker[%d] made a Q product\n", w);

    //"Return" resources to stockpile
    stock_A++;
    stock_B++;
    stock_C++;
    printf("Worker[%d] returns stock for P product\n", w);
    printf("Stock: A=%d, B=%d, C=%d left\n", stock_A, stock_B, stock_C);
}

//R prouction method, needs 1A, 1C
void *produce_R(void *worker)
{
    int w = (int) worker; //Worker id
    
    //Wait if ther are not enough tools 
    while (stock_A < 1 || stock_C < 1) {
        printf("Not enough resources for worker[%d] for R\n", w);
        sem_wait(&sem_worker[w]); //Worker set to wait
        sleep(4); //Subject to change for sure
        printf("Resuming worker's [%d] production for R\n", w);
    }

    //If there are tool to produce then
    printf("Worker[%d] takes resources from pool for R\n", w);
    stock_A--;
    stock_B--;
    stock_C--;
    printf("Stock: A=%d, B=%d, C=%d left\n", stock_A, stock_B, stock_C);

    //Random wait to simulate prod
    sleep(rand() % 4);
    printf("Worker[%d] made a R product\n", w);

    //"Return" resources to stockpile
    stock_A++;
    stock_B++;
    stock_C++;
    printf("Worker[%d] returns stock for R product\n", w);
    printf("Stock: A=%d, B=%d, C=%d left\n", stock_A, stock_B, stock_C);
}

int main(void) {

    int i;
    pthread_t th[4]; //Number of threads to work with

    printf("Setting sems...");
    if (sem_init(&sem_worker[0], 0, 1) < 0) error();
    if (sem_init(&sem_worker[1], 0, 1) < 0) error();
    if (sem_init(&sem_worker[2], 0, 1) < 0) error();
    if (sem_init(&sem_worker[3], 0, 1) < 0) error();

    //Create threads
    printf("Create threads...");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, produce_Q, (void*)i) < 0) error(); //4Q production
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, produce_R, (void*)i) < 0) error(); //4R production
    }

    //Wait for thread death
    printf("Waiting for death...");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) < 0) error();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Problem**

I'm not getting my expected output which is, that each function executes 4 times (4Q and 4R), there will be moments when A, B or C resources will be 0 and one of those threads are going to be waiting for resources availability.

I control this here:

```
while (stock_A < 1 || stock_B < 1 || stock_C < 1) {
        printf("Not enough resources for worker[%d] for Q\n", w);
        sem_wait(&sem_worker[w]); //Worker set to wait
        sleep(4); //StackOverflow question here
        printf("Resuming worker's [%d] production for Q\n", w);
    }
```

but it is not enough... I implemented that 'sleep(4)' as a 'patch that works' but that does not solve my main issue:

**"There are workers that wait for resources but do not produce afterwads,
Am I missing something in that wait code chunk?"**

Comment: `sleep()` is a *timing* function, not a synchronization function.  You could plausibly use it to model time actually spent by the production machinery you are simulating, but it has no appropriate part to play in synchronizing their activities.

Comment: You declare `sem_worker` as an array with two elements, but then proceed to use it as if it had four.  Undefined behavior results.

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a multitude of problems.  Some of the larger ones are:

- you launch 8 threads but join only four (see also below).  You cannot join the other four because you have overwritten their thread identifiers:

  > ```
  >      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  >          if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, produce_Q, (void*)i) < 0) error(); //4Q production
  >          if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, produce_R, (void*)i) < 0) error(); //4R production
  >      }
  > ```

  Note in particular that at each iteration, you are storing the thread identifier for each new thread in the same array element.  If you do not join the other four as well, then you cannot be confident that they will complete their work before being forcibly terminated when the overall program exits.
- You are using multiple independent semaphores to protect access to the same shared variables.  This is incorrect and ineffective.  Multiple resources can be protected by the same semaphore or mutex, but the point is to prevent multiple threads accessing shared variables at the same time, so if threads need only lock any one of several semaphores to obtain access then there is no effective protection.
- You must synchronize *all* accesses to the shared variables.  That includes to test their values in the condition of your `while` loops.
- Once a thread finishes accessing the shared variables, it needs to *unlock* the semaphore with `sem_post()` to allow other threads to acquire it.  Your threads never do that.  It would make sense in this simulation for the threads to unlock the semaphore after claiming resources but before "producing" their product.  In that case, they would want to lock it again before returning the resources, and release it again afterward.
- As I wrote in comments, `sleep()` is not a synchronization function.  It has no valid part to play in synchronization.  You may find, however, that without those calls, your program has trouble making progress.  This is because programs that have a requirement to suspend thread execution pending a condition being satisfied should, generally, be built around *condition variables*.  These allow threads to suspend until being notified that it is worthwhile to test the condition, instead of acquiring the needed lock and testing the condition at every opportunity.

  - However, the appropriate locking object for use with pthreads condition variables is a (pthreads) mutex, not a semaphore.  If you want to use semaphores then you need a different paradigm.

Additionally, your program has a somewhat odd structure.  Not only does it attempt to use semaphores where a mutex + condition variable would be more natural, but a more typical approach to such a production simulation problem would involve just one thread for each production line, each executing a function that loops to produce multiple items.  Such a looping structure would be more amenable to using semaphores.  It would work like this:

1. There is a separate semaphore for each thread.  *Only one* is initialized with value 1; the other (the rest) are initialized with value 0.
2. Threads are forced into a strict round-robin sequence for acquiring locks.  To do this, when each thread exits a critical region, it unlocks *the next thread's* semaphore.
3. When threads finish their normal work, they must continue to participate in the round-robin semaphore locking until all other threads have finished their work, too.
4. There must, therefore, be another one or more pieces of shared data by which the threads can determine when all the work is done.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I appreciate all the effort and in depth answer. This greatly helps me.